# Parity - what --tracing and --pruning options use to get all blocks fastest way

Tags: parity, synchronization

I need download all blocks to be able to get all history transactions to create some statistics like mean Ether amount etc. Is it necessery to use *--pruning archive* and use ~ 1TB od disk? Or default setting with *--tracing on* will give what I need?

Comment: Hi, may I inquire how did you proceed eventually? I was trapped by the same problem. Thanks!

Comment: I used --fat-db on --tracing on options. But it is still more than 100GB and syncing many days (like more than ten days using AWS cloud instance).

Comment: I see. This morning I tried to add the `--gcmode=archive` and it finally works. I only have about 200G SSD.. I will see how much I can sync, and do some mining from there. Thanks!